# Router can’t send a file bigger than 8 Mbto printer

Tags: printer, print-server

I have connected my Epson wired printer to my ISP router by Huawei. Everything works fine except for one big problem. If I try to print a document/image that is any bigger than 8MB after spooling, it fails. So even a 2MB image can’t be printed (As the size increases after spooling).

I don’t know if it is my printer’s problem or the router’s. I am thinking it’s a router issue since the printer doesn’t receive anything to start with. I tried from multiple computers and the same result (although they were all using the same drivers, that could be the issue). The print queue just shows a generic ‘Error’. Event viewer also doesn’t show anything useful.

Are there any alternative drivers I can use to isolate the issue? Is there a way to get more details on the error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So to clarify: can you add the model numbers of the printer and router involved; affirm that you *can* print a test page; indicate what *sort* of print server is on the router to the best of your ability (guessing you enabled a samba configuration); if there is any way to monitor resource usage using the the router's GUI, esp memory and/or process enumeration & status

Comment: Also, importantly - HOW is the printer connected to the router? If its via USB it likely IS the router, but if its via ethernet, and the printers ip address us in the same subnet as ither computers its almost certainly not the router.